# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm using Gson to parse a JSON strings like this one:

```
{"showapi_res_code": 0,
  "showapi_res_error": "1",
  "showapi_res_body": {
    "totalNum": 44,
    "ret_code": 0
   }
 }
```

When I use the following code everything works fine:

```
Bean bean = gson.fromJson(stringFromSource, Bean.class);

public class Bean{
    int showapi_res_code;
    String showapi_res_error;
    Body showapi_res_body;

    public static class Body{
        int totalNum;
        int ret_code;
    }
}
```

But when I use the following code things don't quite work:

```
Bean1 bean1 = gson.fromJson(stringFromSource, Bean1.class);

public class Bean1 {
    int showapi_res_code;
    String showapi_res_error;
    String showapi_res_body;
}
```

I get this exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 3 column 24 path $.showapi_res_body

How can I make this work using Gson?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GSON: Expected a string but was BEGIN\_OBJECT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571412/gson-expected-a-string-but-was-begin-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add separate class not inner class

```
public class Bean{
    int showapi_res_code;
    String showapi_res_error;
    Body showapi_res_body;
} 

public class Body{
        int totalNum;
        int ret_code;
    }
```

Or

```
public class Bean{
        int showapi_res_code;
String showapi_res_error;
HashMap<String,Integer> showapi_res_body;

public int getShowapi_res_code() {
    return showapi_res_code;
}

public void setShowapi_res_code(int showapi_res_code) {
    this.showapi_res_code = showapi_res_code;
}

public String getShowapi_res_error() {
    return showapi_res_error;
}

public void setShowapi_res_error(String showapi_res_error) {
    this.showapi_res_error = showapi_res_error;
}

public HashMap<String, Integer> getShowapi_res_body() {
    return showapi_res_body;
}

public void setShowapi_res_body(HashMap<String, Integer> showapi_res_body) {
    this.showapi_res_body = showapi_res_body;
}
}
```

To get the detail

```
Bean bean1 = gson.fromJson(stringFromSource, Bean1.class);
int totalNum = (Integer)bean1.getShowapi_res_body().get("totalNum");
int ret_code= (Integer)bean1.getShowapi_res_body().get("ret_code");
```

Comment: I follow your suggestion,


    HashMap<String, String> stringMap=map.showapi_res_body;
    String string=stringMap.get("showapi_res_body");

but the result is like this,


 > [Ljava.lang.String;@1de0aca6
 
not the string,how should i get the stirng 


> {
    "totalNum": 44,
    "ret_code": 0
   }

Comment: I follow your suggestion,


    `HashMap<String, String> stringMap=map.showapi_res_body;
    String string=stringMap.get("showapi_res_body");`

but the result is like this,


 `[Ljava.lang.String;@1de0aca6`
 
not the string,how should i get the stirng 


` {
    "totalNum": 44,
    "ret_code": 0
   }`

Comment: the answer is ok,Thank you very musch,I want to ask you ,how i could get the linebreak int the comment,i try it ,but i failed,I am Chinese，the English is not good

Comment: @xujun, Sorry , I don't have any idea.. How to linebreak in the comment

Comment: OK,thanks for your patience，and your answer sloves my problem.  

I want to accept your answer,but I donn't know how to operate.

Comment: @xujun, Please see this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess that's obvious, If you want it to be String, your JSON should have the field as a String type.

```
{"showapi_res_code": 0,
  "showapi_res_error": "1",
  "showapi_res_body": "{ \"totalNum\": 44, \"ret_code\": 0}"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `showapi_res_body` is not a `String` value. In your previous example you use a `Body` object, I suggest you to use the same. If you want to output a `String`, try to do it manually like:

```
public static class Body { 

    int totalNum;
    int ret_code; 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "totalNum = " + totalNum + ", ret_code = " + ret_code;
    }
}
```

Then you can call:

```
String output = bean1.showapi_res_body.toString();
```

Comment: Terlingen,if I use like this,the result of string is not json. Do you have a better way to it?