# Why am i getting this error - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

This is my response
`{"message":"Success","draft_id":"5a9f70021207b061128b4567"}`

this is my POJO class:

```
public class SaveNoteModel {

    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("draft_id")
    @Expose
    private String draftId;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getDraftId() {
        return draftId;
    }

    public void setDraftId(String draftId) {
        this.draftId = draftId;
    }
}
```

I have used scalars retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0 for converting all response into the string. 
this is retrofit call

```
ApiInterface apiInterface = RetrofitClient.getStringClient(ApiConstants.SAVE).create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<String> call = apiInterface.saveNoteCall(userid,pcontract,scontract,action_type,headline,description,mediaOption,media,msf_symbol,mediaUrl,fileName,mediaIcon);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                Log.d("Retrofit", String.format("Data is: %s", response.body()));

                String res  =  response.body().toString();
                //res=  "{"+ "object_: "+res+"}";
                SaveNoteModel menuModel = new Gson().fromJson(res, SaveNoteModel.class);
                if (menuModel != null) {
                    onResponseReceiveEvent.getSuccess(menuModel);
                } else {
                    onResponseReceiveEvent.getFailure();
                    Log.d("Retrofit", String.format("Error is: %s", response.errorBody()));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
                onResponseReceiveEvent.getFailure();
                Log.d("Retrofit", String.format("Error is: %s", t));
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GSON: Expected a string but was BEGIN\_OBJECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571412/gson-expected-a-string-but-was-begin-object)

Comment: your retrofit call maybe like `Call<String>` but in response your are getting object for this your retrofit call must be `Call<JsonObject>`

Comment: @HemantParmar as you shared a link I am unable to resolve in my code. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an object instead of a string. It expected in string. you can change return type to object or you can return a string. In JSON [ ... ] represents array, { ... } represents object, [ {...} ] is array containing one object. Try using

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Message[] message= gson.fromJson(json, Message[].class);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(message));
System.out.println(message[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but in my case it goes in to void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) . If it goes on void onResponse() I can do as you told.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to return an object of `SaveNoteModel` instead of a string Change your code like this,

```
ApiInterface apiInterface = RetrofitClient.getStringClient(ApiConstants.SAVE).create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<SaveNoteModel> call = apiInterface.saveNoteCall(userid,pcontract,scontract,action_type,headline,description,mediaOption,media,msf_symbol,mediaUrl,fileName,mediaIcon);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<SaveNoteModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SaveNoteModel> call, Response<SaveNoteModel> response) {
            Log.d("Retrofit", String.format("Data is: %s", response.body()));

            String res  =  response.body().toString();
            //res=  "{"+ "object_: "+res+"}";
            SaveNoteModel menuModel = new Gson().fromJson(res, SaveNoteModel.class);
            if (menuModel != null) {
                onResponseReceiveEvent.getSuccess(menuModel);
            } else {
                onResponseReceiveEvent.getFailure();
                Log.d("Retrofit", String.format("Error is: %s", response.errorBody()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SaveNoteModel> call, Throwable t) {
            call.cancel();
            onResponseReceiveEvent.getFailure();
            Log.d("Retrofit", String.format("Error is: %s", t));
        }
```

NOTE : also change the return type in your `ApiInterface` class to `SaveNoteModel`